# occupancy_grid_utils with ros hydro

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use `occupancy_grid_utils/ray_tracer.h` library in my ros program for localization.But i get an error due to `occupancy_grid_utils/ray_tracer.h` library does not exist in ros hydro.I got these errors;

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):Could not find a package configuration file provided by occupancy_grid_utils with any of the following names:

occupancy_grid_utilsConfig.cmake
occupancy_grid_utils-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "occupancy_grid_utils" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
or set "occupancy_grid_utils_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
above files.  If "occupancy_grid_utils" provides a separate development
package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
particle_filter/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)`

Is there any way to use this library in ros hydro?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103296/occupancy_grid_utils-with-ros-hydro/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have found this great repo for my problem.

https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/occupancy_grid_utils

---

Originally posted by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) with karma: 114 on 2013-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on 2015-08-25**:
Hey i am trying to use the same repo to use the grid_construction_node to visualize the occupancy grid with a Hokuyo  mounted on a husky but I get the error stating no map received. Did you manage to make it work? Could you help me with this ?